# Android Radio Button1

Tags: android

I want to read the ID on the Radio Button and use the Intent which I'm going to start in another activity, my aim is to read the ID on the Radio Button and Show it in the next event XML

**xml:**

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="64dp" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio0"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checked="true"
            android:text="Male" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Female" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Amphibian" />
    </RadioGroup>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="Submit" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity:

```
package com.work.radbtn;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
Button btn;
RadioGroup radGrp;
RadioButton radBtn1, radBtn2, radBtn3;
String lang;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        radGrp = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);
        radBtn1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio0);
        radBtn2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio1);
        radBtn3 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio2);
        /*radBtn1.setOnClickListener(radBtnOnClickListener);
        radBtn2.setOnClickListener(radBtnOnClickListener);
        radBtn3.setOnClickListener(radBtnOnClickListener);*/


        btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                if (radBtn1.isSelected())
                    lang = lang + radBtn1.getId();
                else if (radBtn2.isSelected())
                    lang = lang + radBtn2.getId();
                else if (radBtn3.isSelected())
                    lang = lang + radBtn3.getId();

                else {

                Intent i = new Intent();
                i.setClass(MainActivity.this, MainActivity1.class);
                String temp = lang.toString();
                i.putExtra("me", temp);

                startActivity(i);
                }
            }
        });
    }



}
```

Second XML

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity1" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="184dp"
    android:text="TextView" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
    android:text="Button" />
```

MainActivity1

```
    package com.work.radbtn;



import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity1 extends Activity {

TextView txt;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_activity1);
        txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        Intent i = getIntent();
        Bundle bundle = i.getExtras();
        String temp = bundle.getString("me");
        txt.setText(temp);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_activity1, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When creating the radio button array, store each button's Id in an array, like this (within a `for` with loop variable `i`):

```
for (int i=0; i<NumberOfButtons; i++)
    // Create button i
    radioButtonId[i] = radioButton[i].getId();
```

Then you can get the array index of the selected button like this:

```
private int getSelected() {
    int selectedId = radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
    int selected = -1;
    for (int i=0; i<radioButtonId.length; i++) {
        if ( selectedId == radioButtonId[i] ) {
            selected = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    return selected;
}
```